# meaning of pattern return var && var ==='something' in javascript

Tags: javascript

in a function, I saw `return myVar && anotherVar === 'error';`

Does this statement return a true / false depends on whether the && statement evaluate to be true or false after evaluating both conditions? so if let's say both a and b are true, the return result should be true, right? I thought so, but when I test it out in chrome console, I got error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` when I do `var a = 'abc', b = '123';` then `return a && b;`

Any thoughts?

Comment: That works just fine here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/RWQKJx -- it returns the second value, as expected (which is truthy enough for JS purposes). Please show a snippet of code that actually triggers this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is does not necessarily evaluate both conditions. Logical operators in javascript use something called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) so that the system only runs the first condition if it can determine the result based on the first condition alone. The code is equivalent to this:

```
if (myVar)
{
    //if the first condition fails we never enter the block
    // and never check this condition
    if (anotherVar === 'error')
    {
       return true;
    }  
}
return false;
```

This is a common pattern that is pretty easy to understand once you've seen it a few times, and therefore it's almost always preferable to use the shorter form you encountered for the question over writing out the whole mess from this answer.

For your test, rather than calling `return`, just `debug.print` or `debug.log` the result.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because you are not using `return` inside a function, try the following in any console:

```
function foo() {
    var a = "abc", b = "123";
    return a && b;
};
foo();
```

As per the `&&` question, thats a logical AND operator, if the first (`a`) in this case, is `false`, the second won't be evaluated.

Comment: @taxicala its partially my fault, because your answer do solve the problem in the description, however, my title indicates otherwise, to explain the meaning. I do really really really appreciate your answer, and + 1 ed :) Thank you soooo much!